# Importing data from excel to sql server table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, package, ssms

I have created a basic package using excel as source and sql server database as destination. I have inserted 5 rows in excel and they are getting populated in sql server table without any error.
when i add 2 new rows to the excel file, i want only those two newly added rows to be added in the database table , without previous rows being populated again.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: How would the server know that those 2 rows are actually "new"? If you have a column in your table that can act as a unique key you could check for previously inserted rows before insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can try left joining the excel source with the sql table and then filtering out any rows that already have a match:

[image: Left join flow]

Notes:

- Excel Source is your Excel Data
- Sort is there because your data always needs to be sorted on your join keys when using a Merge Join
- OLE DB Source is your SQL table with existing Excel data in it.  I have an ORDER BY in my query and the IsSorted property set to TRUE so the data is already sorted coming in.
- The Merge Join is peforming a left outer join.
- The conditional Split is splitting on a condition that says ISNULL(name_of_field_from_ole_db_source)
- The OLE DB Destination writes out to SQL (same table as being used in the OLE DB Source node).